# Convert a string to array format java script

Tags: javascript

I hava a string like this `"sum 123,645,423,123,432";`

How can i convert this string to be like this:

```
{
  “sum”: [ 123,645,423,123,432 ]
}
```

I try it like this:

```
var arr = "sum 123,645,423,123,432";
var c = arr.split(',');
console.log(c);
VM3060:1 (5) ["sum 123", "645", "423", "123", "432"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try to convert it like that?

Comment: Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt

Comment: Posted an answer below based on your try, hope it will help you somehow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, i `.split()` the string by whitespace, that returns me an array like this `["sum" , "123,645,423,123,432"]`

Instead of writing `var name = str.split(" ")[0]` and `var arrString = str.split(" ")[1]` i used an destructuring assignment

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Next step is to split the `arrString` up by `,` and then `.map()` over each element and convert it to an number with `Number()`.

Finally i assign an object to `result` with a dynamic key `[name]` and set `arr` to the dynamic property.

```js
var str = "sum 123,645,423,123,432";

var [name,arrString] = str.split(" ");
var arr = arrString.split(",").map(Number);

let result = {
   [name]: arr
}

console.log(result);

//reverse

var [keyname] = Object.keys(result);
var strngArr = arr.join(",");

var str = `${keyname} ${strngArr}`

console.log(str);
```

Comment: work but the value in the array must be number not string

Comment: @lfaruki glad to see you removed the typings. You can improve your answer by pointing out to some destructuring post to guide others to "what those square brackets mean". Eventually add a short explanation above, or as comments in your code with what you've done there, so it will be easier for beginners to understand.

Comment: Hay @Ifaruki how can i reverse it to the same string after i get the array from the server?

Comment: @BaruchMashasha try `var result = arr.join(",")`

Comment: thanks king...but when i do join it return 12,43,654,354,234 without the "sum"....

Comment: @BaruchMashasha well look at my edit, i have added it at the bottom

Comment: @Ifaruki Amazing, and the explanation was excellent, thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const str = "sum 123,645,423,123,432";

const splittedString = str.split(" ");
const key = splittedString[0];
const values = splittedString[1].split(",").map(Number);

const myObject = {
  [key]: [...values]
};

console.log(myObject);
```

Comment: work but the value in the array must be number not string

Comment: It works, but it's Typescript, not Javascript. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration`

Comment: @JeremyThille yeah sure this is a typed version sorry. I removed the types

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to dot that,one way to do it using [String.prototype.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```js
let str = "sum 123,645,423,123,432";
let split_str = str.split(' ');
let expected = {};
expected[split_str[0]] = split_str[1].split(',');
console.log(expected);
```

Comment: work but the value in the array must be number not string

Comment: @BaruchMashasha have a look now :)

Answer (score 1):

This solution is equivalent to @Yohan Dahmani with the use of **destructuring array** for more legible code.

```js
const str = "sum 123,645,423,123,432";

const [key,numbersStr] = str.split(' ');

const numbersArr = numbersStr.split(',').map(n => parseInt(n, 10));

const result = {[key]: numbersArr};

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Done. With that concept given I think is enough to find an extended explanation over Internet. I found that basic and not totally related with the question, that's why I didn't explain, maybe it's more interesting to explain what `[key]` means indeed.